# how to generically log enumerable context data in azure apim?

Tags: azure, azure-api-management

Do you have a way to generically log enumerable context data in Azure APIM?  For example, a policy that includes context.Api.Protocols returns:

```
  context.Api.Protocols: System.Collections.Immutable.ImmutableArray`1[
    System.String
  ]
```

However, I want the policy to return a list of the actual protocols instead of just the type. Are there generic code statements or expressions I can include in the policy to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is nothing built-in that I can think of, so probably your best bet is just a string.Join call:

```
string.Join(", ", context.Protocols)
```

Comment: yep that's what I ended up doing